# Issue while using css widht/height value as "inherit", while changing the parent's dimensions dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have created a HTML page where few of the elements were given css as :

.inheritDimensions{
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
}

So, those elements are dependent on the dimensions of its parent elements.

Everything is fine when the page is rendered initially. But (here comes the wierd thing), If I change the heights/widths of the parent elements dynamically, they are not getting reflected(or updated dimensions are not inherited to the .inheritDimensions elements) UNTIL I click on somewhere on the browser!

This problem is seen in Chrome, Safari, IE. Working fine in FF though.

-SuryaPavan

Answer (score 0):

Try adding !important

```
.inheritDimensions{
width: inherit !important;
height: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: No, not working. But if i dint give !important also, its inheriting. But only after a click on somewhere on the browser area :(